# Parse XML in c# depending on nodes on XmlElement

Tags: c#

I need to parse the following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Items>
        <Attr></Attr>
    <Items>
    <Goods>
        <Attr></Attr>
        <Attr></Attr>
        <Attr></Attr>
    </Goods>    
</Response>
```

This xml is stored on `XmlReader output` object . 
Is there any Function to get the first node element Items and store it in an xml element object say `xmlelement1`. And parse/loop through the `xmlelement1` and  perform actions.

Comment: Why not read it into an `XmlDocument` and go from there? If it's that small, it will be the most efficient way. And please don't name reader objects as `output` since they're clearly inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, use the XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("<<PathToXmlFileOnDisk>>");
```

or if you want to load a string of XML:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml("<<XmlText>>");
```

Then go through the thing:

```
foreach(XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("./Response").ChildNodes)
{
   ... //Once for each node under Response, then (Ex: Items has its own ChildNodes)
}
```

Comment: Also you can use recursion to look through each child, and then its children and your stopping case is the node doesn't have anymore children

Comment: Or you can combine this with [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/d271ytdx(v=VS.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml);

XElement xelem1 = doc.Root.Element("Items");

foreach (XElement elem in xelem1.Elements())
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, value: {1}", elem.Name, elem.Value);
```

Comment: Do we have to use any Dll for using LINQ ??

Comment: @user3383301 - No, just add `using System.Xml.Linq;`